# MySql: updating a column with the column's content plus something else

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-update

I'm don't have a lot of knowledge of MySql (or SQL in general) so sorry for the noobness.

I'm trying to update a bunch of String entries this way:

Lets say we have this:

```
commands.firm.pm.Stuff
```

Well I want to convert that into:

```
commands.firm.pm.print.Stuff
```

Meaning, Add the **.print** after pm, before "Stuff" (where Stuff can be any Alphanumerical String).

How would I do this with a MySql Query? I'm sure REGEXP has to be used, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. It finds the last period and inserts your string there:

```
select insert(s, length(s) - instr(reverse(s), '.') + 1, 0, '.print')
from (
    select 'commands.firm.pm.Stuff' as s
) a
```

To update:

```
update MyTable
set MyColumn = insert(MyColumn, length(MyColumn) - instr(reverse(MyColumn), '.') + 1, 0, '.print')
where MyColumn like 'commands.firm.pm.%'
```

Comment: Yes, `INSERT()` is better than CONCAT here.

Comment: Wait, quick question, what does this do? Does it just select or does it actually update the database?

Comment: This is just a select as an example of how to transform the data. See my edit for update example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a str_replace to replace `commands.firm.pm` to `commands.firm.pm.print`

```
$original_str = "commands.firm.pm.15hhkl15k0fak1";
str_replace("commands.firm.pm", "commands.firm.pm.print", $original_str);
```

should output: `commands.firm.pm.print.15hhkl15k0fak1`

then update your table with the new value...How to do it all in one query (get column value and do the update), I do not know. All I can think of is you getting the column value in one query, doing the replacement above, and then updating the column with the new value in a second query.

Answer (score 0):

To update rows that end in `'.Stuff'` only:

```
UPDATE TableX
SET Column = CONCAT( LEFT( CHAR_LENGTH(Column) - CHAR_LENGTH('.Stuff') )
                   , '.print'
                   , '.Stuff'
                   )
WHERE Column LIKE '%.Stuff'
```

---

To update all rows - by appending `.print` just before the last dot `.`:

```
UPDATE TableX
SET Column = CONCAT( LEFT( CHAR_LENGTH(Column) 
                           - CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column, '.', -1))
                         )
                   , 'print.'
                   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column, '.', -1)
                   )
WHERE Column LIKE '%.%'
```

Comment: *"where Stuff can be any Alphanumerical String"*

Comment: This ALMOST works, but the problem is that, like I said, Stuff is any alphanumerical string, so it isn't called "Stuff". I have to figure out what stuff is. All I know is that it is the String after the last "." character.

Comment: You can use the 2nd version then. Or RedFilter's much better version with `Insert()`.

Comment: See [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html)